# Firestore exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using GCP with node 16 and firestore. I'm getting data of subcollection and update by id. In `console.log(subCollect.id);` and `console.log(subCollect.data());` the information logged is correct. In update command I receive the folowing error

```
 var subCollecPromises = [];
 var parentPromises = [];

 var querySnapshot = await db.collectionGroup("mysubcollection")
 .where('name', '==', "subname")
 .where('sequence', '==', 2).get();

querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

  var data = doc.data();

  if(data.enable){
    var childRef;
    var parentRef;

    childRef = doc.ref.parent;
    parentRef = childRef.parent;

    subCollecPromises.push(doc.ref.get());
    parentPromises.push(parentRef.get());
  }
});

const arrsubCollecSnap = await Promise.all(subCollecPromises);
const arrsubParentSnap = await Promise.all(parentPromises);

for (let index = 0; index < arrsubParentSnap.length; index++) {
  const item = arrsubParentSnap[index];

  var parentData = item.data();

  var subCollect = arrsubCollecSnap[index];

  console.log(subCollect.id);
  console.log(subCollect.data());

  await db.collection("mysubcollection").doc(subCollect.id)
  .update({sequence: 3, datetime: new Date()});

  await sendMail(parentData.mail);
}
```

Error in update:

```
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: no entity to update: app: "dev~myapp-backend"
path <
  Element {
    type: "mysubcollection"
    name: "Vuxx2Hy9xprtm7tZFyne"
  }
>

    code: 5,
  details: 'no entity to update: app: "dev~myapp-backend"\n' +
    'path <\n' +
    '  Element {\n' +
    '    type: "mysubcollection"\n' +
    '    name: "Vuxx2Hy9xprtm7tZFyne"\n' +
    '  }\n' +
    '>\n',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(1) { 'content-type' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way for update a subcollection is starts at parent collection:

```
await db.collection("parentCollection").doc(parentId).collection("mysubcollection").doc(subCollect.id).update({sequence: 3, datetime: new Date()});
```